# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build

Tags: java, gradle, build

При запуске любой сборки выпадает сообщение: (Gradle 6.9.1)

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

1. Делаю анализ `gradlew help --warning-mode=all`
2. Выдает

   build_73q9ybvm0kop01p5xu7z5uhp1$_run_closure2.doCall(C:\Users****\Documents\Java_projects\Java_Education\build.gradle:24)
   (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

*24 строчка это     compile 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0' (в dependencies)*

3. Делаю стектрейс (gradlew help --warning-mode=all --stacktrace
   ), вывод

The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation configuration instead. Consult the up
grading guide for further information:

**Содержимое build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    //id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}




dependencies {
    implementation('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59')
    implementation('com.codeborne:selenide:5.22.2')
    //testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-selenide:${allureVersion}")
    testImplementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.32')
    testImplementation("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:4.4.3")
    compile 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'

}


test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

Понял причина в устаревшем слове compile, пошел читать статью, если у кого есть быстро решение, как поменять строку, буду благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
compile 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'
```

поменять на

```
testImplementation('org.testng:testng:7.4.0')
```